# Regex matching all but last occurence of character

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to put together a Regex matching all but last occurrence of a specific character (say exclamation mark **!**), into a group, and then everything else into another group.

Examples:

*a!1*

- G1: a
- G2: 1

*a!!1*

- G1: a!
- G2: 1

a!1!a!!a

- G1: a!1!a!
- G2: a

It is safe to assume that the special character cannot be at the start, or the end of the string.

Ideally I want all this to be achieved in

- one Regex
- no additional manipulation with strings
- without using RightToLeft

Thanks,
Stevo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(.*)\!(.*)
```

Matched test inputs/outputs here
http://www.myregextester.com/index.php

Comment: Thanks. I was simplifying a much more complicated case into this example, which turns out to be really easy to solve. Introspectively good job. You can do even simpler (.*)!(.*)

Answer (score 0):

this should catch anything before the last ! in a capturing group, and everything after in the other capturing group

```
(.*)!([^!]*)
```